# "IllegalsStateException closed" in HttpUrlConnection while download file

Tags: java, android

I have random IllegalstateException crash in Fabric. But can't reproduce it.
[image]

Users download file from server. For download I use regular HttpUrlConnection and read bytes from InputStream in while. Call this in foreground service with separate thread. On some iteration of reading this crash happen. I close InputStream only in finally, so it can't be closed before while finish.

Android 6, 7, 8, 9. Interesting that 100% Samsung, maybe Samsung has some specific behavior? Also interesting that this happen always near finish of download. For example from 2738688 bytes was downloaded 2716156 and only 22532‬ left. All crashes near the end of download.

```java
public static Response downloadFile(String url, String tmpFile) throws IOException {
        InputStream is = null;
        OutputStream os = null;
        Response result;
        try {
            URL urlFile = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) urlFile.openConnection();
            connection.connect();

            long size = connection.getContentLength();
            int code = connection.getResponseCode();
            Map<String, List<String>> responseHeaders = connection.getHeaderFields();
            result = new Response(code, size, responseHeaders);

            if (code != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                return result;
            }

            is = connection.getInputStream();
            os = new FileOutputStream(tmpFile);

            final byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int read;
            //This read random crash
            while ((read = is.read(buf)) != -1) {
                os.write(buf, 0, read);
            }
            os.flush();
        } finally {
            if (is != null) {
                is.close();
            }
            if (os != null) {
                os.close();
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Not an answer, but you must get and check the response code before anything else, specifically before getting the content length or header fields. Both those operations can throw exceptions, as can `getInputStream()`.

Comment: I'm not sure, but is it possible that a server connection timeout causes this issue?